# SQL Linked Server "IBM DB2 for i IBMDASQL OLE DB Provider" / IBMDASQL Stopped Working - No Errors

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server, iseries

We have a linked server to pull data from an AS400 that worked every day for years, but randomly stopped working last night.

- When we do test connection / run a test open query against the linked server, it just spins and spins for hours, no failure or error message is provided.
- We have tried rebooting the SQL server
- We also use the the IBM i Access Client Solutions to pull data from the same server/host with the same credentials and have no issues, we are able to pull the data.
- We heard from our IT operations team that this patch was applied last night our server: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/july-12-2022-kb5015874-monthly-rollup-f7d12c29-5f30-4038-a614-0ed0de7aa931
- We also noticed that there seems to be extra "Authentication" steps in our organization as of last night as well. We had to re-log into a lot of applications/intranet pages/etc. that we use normally.
- We are trying to open tickets/get in touch with someone that can help us from the server we are trying to pull data from, but it is a slow process getting help.
- We're not network people so we're a little stuck after digging into this for many hours. We do have some operations people we are asking for help on but not sure what questions to ask.

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Did you try running the IBM i Access Client on the SQL Server machine? What you describe looks like a network problem, so you'll want to try and isolate it.

Comment: yes the IBM i Access client runs on the same SQL server machine without issue. It's only the linked server that is having an issue.